# iOS share extension dismiss keyboard

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

I'm implementing a share extension for my app, so far everything is going good except I can't seem to dismiss the keyboard that automatically opens using the default layout/storyboard.

I'm keeping the default design/layout (SLComposeServiceViewController) which includes the preview image and UITextview, the UITextview automatically gets in focus which opens the keyboard.

Normally this is fine, but if you're not logged in my app I display an UIAlertController saying you need to login to share. The problem is the keyboard opens at the same time as the alert.

I've tried `[self.view endEditing:YES];` and `[self.textView resignFirstResponder];` in both viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear and viewWillAppear with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer! I didn't read the docs very carefully...

I had to do `[self.textView resignFirstResponder];` in `-(void)presentationAnimationDidFinish`

Comment: THIS!!! I have been looking for days and failed to see that overriding presentationAnimationDidFinish was the key.

Answer (score 0):

my way is to use `UITextViewDelegate`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.textView.delegate = self;
     self.canShare = NO;
     [self.view setAlpha:0.0];
}
```

change `canShare` to YES in your check login logic

```
- (void)checkLoggedIn {
    if ([[ShareAccountManager checkLoggedIn]) {
        self.canShare = YES;
        [self.view setAlpha:1.0];
    }
}
```

and implement method `textViewShouldBeginEditing`

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (self.canShare) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShareViewController` inherits from `SLComposeServiceViewController`. That is what causes the keyboard to be presented, it has a `textView`.

Replace that `SLComposeServiceViewController` with a simple `UIViewController` and the keyboard will not appear.

Recreate the UI inside that controller inside a simple `UIViewController`. That will give you more power over what is the responder.