# Dismiss keyboard opened by the sharing app when in Share Extension without text input fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, ios-app-extension

After selecting text in a textview/textfield in an app (Messages, for example), you can select `Share` from the popup menu to share the text. Since you were editing text at the time you selected/shared, the keyboard is visible. Once you have selected an share target app, the keyboard will continue to be visible when the target app's extension appears. I need to dismiss this keyboard so that other elements on the screen are visible and accessible. In my case, I have no editable fields (e.g. textField/textView) in the custom view controller that appears in the extension. (i.e. to become firstResponder)

The usual solutions that do not work:

1. Use the Dismiss button in the KB - does not exist on iPhone
2. `[self.view endEditing:YES]` - No subview in my view is firstResponder
3. `[self.textView resignFirstResponder]` - No textView/textField in my view (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28119785/650365)
4. `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES]` - `sharedApplication` is unavailable in share extensions
5. `[theViewController setEditing:NO animated:YES]`

Hacky solution that does work (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34299724/650365):

- Add a textField to your VC in the storyboard/XIB and set a reference outlet in your .m file. (You can place it off-screen or mark it Hidden.)
- In viewDidLoad, run `becomeFirstResponder`.
- In viewDidAppear, run `resignFirstResponder` on that same textField.

How can I dismiss the keyboard in a Share Extension on iPhone without adding extra textField/textViews?

Comment: Did you try to dismiss the keyboard using the methods you mentioned in the viewWillDisappear of viewDidDisappear?

Comment: At button action of share call `[self.view endEditing:YES]`

Comment: @Alex Which VC's viewWillDisappear are you thinking? The sharing app (that is disappearing) is not under my control. Is there an interstitial VC you know of that I can hook into, perhaps as a delegate?

Comment: @Vinodh I don't have control of the sharing app (where the action is initiated), only the receiving app.

Comment: If by sharing app you mean a different application which is in background, in this case I am surprised the keyboard was not resigned automatically by the system. keyWindow contains the current window, which probably is not the one that launched the keyboard. On the other hand, the [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] array should contain the list of all the windows, hidden and visibles. May be you can try to iterated through the "windows" array and resign the first responder on all of them.

Comment: @Alex - Yeah, it seems all the good magic tricks originate from `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`. Unfortunately as I said in #4 in the Q, sharedApplication is unavailable in share extensions. For sandboxing reasons, I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShareViewController` inherits from `SLComposeServiceViewController`. That is what causes the keyboard to be presented, it has a `textView`.

Replace that `SLComposeServiceViewController` with a simple `UIViewController` and the keyboard will not appear.